# How do I toggle boolean values in JSON object using express?

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I am a beginner and have just finished my first MERN CRUD app. I've thought about a few ways to improve the app. The app is a todo list and has a complete button. The complete button will score a line through an item in the todo list. The complete button triggers a function which will make a post request (shown below) to the nodejs/express backend server. When the "isCompleted" field in the Mongo model is set to "true" (by default it's false), the item will be scored out. I tried to find a way to toggle the boolean values in the "isCompleted" field, whenever the complete button is clicked. This way you can unscore an item. But I just couldn't figure out how to implement this. Any ideas?

```
exports.updateEntry = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const entry = await Entry.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {isCompleted: true});



    return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: entry
    });

} catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        error: 'Server Error'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before the

`const entry = await Entry.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {isCompleted: true});`

you need to fetch the current value of the variable, should be something like this (been a long time since i worked with mongo):

`const isCompleted = await Entry.findById({_id:req.params.id}).select('isCompleted')`

then use `!isCompleted` to get the toggled value, like this:
`const entry = await Entry.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {isCompleted: !isCompleted});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware at top of your function (maybe you need it at a general level, so you can use it at index.js of your express project).

Then you can do this:

```
exports.updateEntry = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const entry = await Entry.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id}, {isCompleted: req.body.isCompleted});
      return res.status(200).json({
       success: true,
      data: entry
      });
} catch (err) {
   return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error: 'Server Error'
});}
```